# Plotting Graphs in c

Tags: c

i am beginner in c programming, i am currently using gedit of ubuntu 10.04 to write c prog, i want to plot a graph, but i am able to do it, can any one tell me hw it can be done or else is there any way to extract the data from the output to spreadsheet where i can plot the req, graph??
I appreciate your help..n thanx!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Medsphere has some pretty great [GTK# widgets](http://medsphere.org/community/project/medsphere-widgets) for graphing (among other things), but you'll need to be a little more clear about your input/output requirements to get more specific help.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
int i, k;
int co=100;
int L=1;
float A=0.02;
int t[]={0, 5, 10};
float T[21][3];
float y;
float x[] = {0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85, 0.90, 0.95, 1};
printf("distance     temperature\n");
for(k=0;k<=2;k++)
{
for (i=0;i<=20;i++)
 {
y=exp(-(A*3.14*3.14)*t[k]/(L*L));
T[i][k]=co*y*sin(3.14*x[i]/L);
T[0][k]=0;
T[20][k]=0;
printf("%f %d    %f\n", x[i], t[k], T[i][k]);
}
}
} this is my code i want to plot T[i][k] v/s x[i]

Comment: That is utterly unreadable - maybe edit the question and put it in there. Also, my answer was related to C#, and your code (and now the question edit) indicates that you're actually speaking about C, which is a horse of a different color. If you have the data in a spreadsheet, I'd do what Marco said and use gnuplot, without writing a C program at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could you this character(■) to represent the count in the graph. This is a character that can be printed by

```
printf("%c", (char)254u);
```

Consider some random `float_arr` and `hist` array that hold the count.

**Code**

```
// Function generating random data
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    float random = ((float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX));
    float_arr[i] = random;
    printf("%f  ", random);
}
//Dividing float data into bins
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 1; j <= bins; j++){

        float bin_max = (float)j / (float)bins;
        if (float_arr[i] <= bin_max){
            hist[j]++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
// Plotting histogram
printf("\n\nHistogram of Float data\n");
for (i = 1; i <= bins; i++)
{
    count = hist[i];
    printf("0.%d |", i - 1);
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", (char)254u);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
Histogram of Float data
0.0 |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
0.1 |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
0.2 |■■■■■
0.3 |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
0.4 |■■■■■■■■
0.5 |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
0.6 |■■■■■■■■■■
0.7 |■■■■■■■
0.8 |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
0.9 |■■■■■■■
```

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot (http://www.gnuplot.info/) is a pretty capable and free tool for graphing data.
Your question is not clear as to whether you want to plot data programmatically though.

Comment: if possible prgrammically..or if it is very difficult for a beginner like me, i would llike to know is there any way to extract the output data to spreadsheet where i can plot it...

Comment: I second gnuplot. Very easy to output csv and then feed it to gnuplot.

Answer (score 0):

I think [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net) can help you. It is GPL plotting library which can create a window with yours plot without knowledge of any widgets library. Also it have nice graphics for matrices and 3-ranged data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the same that I have. To do this there are some libraries written to facilitate the work that is more or less this:

1. open a new window
2. draw something. That is coordinates, curves, background, etc.

In c/c++ there are some of these libraries are:

1. libplot, the gnu plot utils www.gnu.org/s/plotutils. Is a very basic one and the documentation have nice examples, to
   plot in svg, png, and other files. Also you can plot in a window or make animations.
2. mathGL is open-gl based.

Another way to make a plot is to generate your data in your c code and then plot it with an other program. It is possible
to run gnuplot and pass your data trough a pipe. But you must use fork and pipes.